# Python Module Installation Error Code 1

Tags: python, pip, pyautogui

Over the last couple of days, I have been having been attempting to install the pyautogui module via pip. it isn't going well. I've attempted the few fixes I've seen online, but none work. I need some help. Here's a copy of my CMD text:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\FrankFritz>py -m pip install pyautogui
Collecting pyautogui
  Using cached PyAutoGUI-0.9.31.zip
Collecting pymsgbox (from pyautogui)
  Using cached PyMsgBox-1.0.3.zip
Collecting PyTweening>=1.0.1 (from pyautogui)
  Using cached PyTweening-1.0.3.zip
Collecting Pillow (from pyautogui)
  Using cached Pillow-3.0.0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
Collecting pyscreeze (from pyautogui)
  Using cached PyScreeze-0.1.8.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\FrankFritz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-yjly5zdh\pyscreeze\setup.p
y", line 6, in <module>
        version=__import__('pyscreeze').__version__,
      File "C:\Users\FrankFritz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-yjly5zdh\pyscreeze\pyscree
ze\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
        from PIL import Image
    ImportError: No module named 'PIL'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\FrankFritz\AppD
ata\Local\Temp\pip-build-yjly5zdh\pyscreeze
```

Thank you in advance, it has been very frustrating.

Comment: The error is telling you that you need to install `PIL`

Answer (score 2):

Install `PIL` first. If you're using Py3, install `Pillow`, a `PIL` substitute.

Answer (score 2):

Press win key + R then type cmd

**in command prompt type:**

`cd xx/pythonxx/scripts`      # xx represents your python directory e.g. `C:/python34/script`

`pip install pillow` # for python 3xx versions

`pip install pil` # for python 2xx versions

`pip install pyautogui` # this should work now

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to install `pyautogui` for Python 3.4 on Windows 7. Finally managed to get it working by doing the following:

```
easy_install.exe Pillow
pip install pyautogui
```

Hope this helps others as well.